# OutOfMemoryError trying to run Cactus unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, ant, cactus

We have a Hudson/Ant build setup.  I have just added a series of Apache Cactus (version 1.8.1) unit tests to the project and am trying to run them after the project builds.  I get the following error when it tries to execute the cactus task: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space."

We have already bumped up the Java heap space as much as we can.  Is there a way to make the Cactus task use less memory?  Or something else I can do within the test cases themselves to reduce the memory footprint?

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely certain the tests do not reveal a memory leak?

Answer (score 0):

When you say you already bumped up the heap 'as much as you can', can you be more specific?  1g?  2g?  Also, why don't you run the Java process with:

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath="my_dump.out"
```

and view the heap dump in a tool like [HPjmeter](http://www.hpjmeter.com) to see what is being held onto in memory?  Otherwise, your sort of operating in the dark.  Can you also menion whether you're running with a 32-bit or 64-bit JVM?